# Angular + Electron - App breaks on refresh or change

Tags: angular, angular-cli

If navigate to the route localhost:4200/login make a change or refresh it works fine.

If i navigate to the route localhost:4200/main which is a submodule (protected by authguard), if i make a change to any components in these pages or refresh i get the following errors.

```
profile:16 GET http://localhost:4200/main/inline.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
12:53:35.010 profile:16 GET http://localhost:4200/main/polyfills.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
12:53:35.019 profile:16 GET http://localhost:4200/main/styles.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
12:53:35.053 profile:16 GET http://localhost:4200/main/vendor.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
12:53:35.053 profile:16 GET http://localhost:4200/main/main.bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
```

i serve my app using **ng serve --watch**

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
node: 6.11.3
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.4
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/common: 4.4.4
@angular/compiler: 4.4.4
@angular/core: 4.4.4
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-rc.1
@angular/forms: 4.4.4
@angular/http: 4.4.4
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.4
@angular/router: 4.4.4
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.4
@angular/language-service: 4.4.4
typescript: 2.5.3
```

Also to note that it always compiles successfully.

```
chunk {common} common.chunk.js, common.chunk.js.map (common) 13.8 kB {main}  [rendered]
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 64.2 kB {vendor} [initial]
chunk {main.module} main.module.chunk.js, main.module.chunk.js.map () 83.2 kB {main} 
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 217 kB {inline} [initial]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 66.4 kB {inline} [initial]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 5.53 MB [initial]

webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: try 
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli

npm cache clean

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: Hey, I just tried as you said and i still have the same problem, thanks for the sugguestion tho

Comment: Do you have a <base> tag in the head of your index.html? If you don't try adding one like <base href="/"> and see if that helps.

Comment: yes i do, this app was creating using the angular cli.   <base href="./"> i added the "." before it for electron.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Well based off your question it sounds like when it's at the /main path, it thinks it's supposed to be importing all the js/css files from a directory with that name and not the base one... And you're using ng serve, not an electron thing..

Comment: Ye its strange, but if i just found if i remove the "dot" . it works fine now... but the electron app is broke now

Comment: From the looks of [this post](https://discuss.atom.io/t/angular-2-routes-breaking-on-electron-app-refresh/28370/4) it looks like it might just be the lack of hash-url. Adding the useHash:true in the routing module might help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156558/discussion-between-jeddai-and-khan).

Comment: that worked thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this post](https://discuss.atom.io/t/angular-2-routes-breaking-on-electron-app-refresh/28370/4), the issue lies in Electron's handling of the HTML5 style URL. In order to get it working, all you should need to do is tell the RouterModule to use the hashed URL, in a similar fashion to Angular 1.

That looks like the following:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/your-route/
  ]...
```